Why does 'Since OpenSSL 3.0' error happen?
Full error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4996   'RSA_size': Since OpenSSL 3.0   Cloud   my_rsa.h    75

How can I solve this problem?
I have installed OpenSSL 3.3.0 for Windows (x64) and included the header files in my C++ project in Visual Studio. I have linked the lib files libssl.lib and libcrypto.lib and added path variable to the \bin folder. My project recognizes the OpenSSL header files, but it keeps giving me the error 'Since OpenSSL 3.0' for many functions.

Check the output tab instead for the full output.

@Botje is right, you should check output tab and provide a complete error message. It is, however, not hard to decipher this error. C4996 is a deprecation warning, so RSA_size is marked as deprecated. And the associated deprecation message is "Since OpenSSL 3.0". Indeed, this symbol was deprecated since OpenSSL 3.0. See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.3/man7/migration_guide.html for more information on changes in 3.0.
This answers your question "why does the error happens". Now, to answer a followup "How can I solve this problem?" - you've got 3 options:

If you can live with always using OpenSSL 3.0+: best option is to stop using deprecated symbols at all, i.e. follow the migration guide I mentioned earlier
If you must support OpenSSL 2, but also want best compatibility with future versions of OpenSSL going forward: best option is to conditionally compile best method. Use can use OPENSSL_VERSION_MAJOR to figure out OpenSSL version you are compiling against. This might require a bit of refactoring as OpenSSL API changed quite a bit.
Finally, for a quick-n-dirty solution, you can just suppress this warning in each place where you are using deprecated methods.

Be aware if you go with option 3, your code might stop working again when you update OpenSSL further (once they remove the deprecated symbols completely), and this time you won't have an option of simply disabling a warning. So if you have to fix things quickly and you choose option 3, you might want to still go with option 1 or 2 later on once time permits - so that your code stays up-to-date with current state of OpenSSL.
